# Uninitialized constant using Twitter ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

In my Rails 3 app I am attempting to display the tweets of users who have stored their twitter handle in my app as `@profile.twitter`. For each of those users I want to search their tweets with a specific hashtag. I'd like to perform the search in an action in my `ProfilesController` and load the tweets in a tabbed container.

I took a crack at the controller action but am getting `uninitialized constant ProfilesController::Twitter`. Can anyone help explain why? This is my first crack at fetching data like this. Below is my code.

**profiles_controller.rb**:

```
def profile_tweets
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @profile.tweets = Twitter.search("#hashtag", "from:#{@profile.twitter}")
  render :json => @tweets
end
```

**Routes.rb**:

```
resources :profiles do
  get :profile_about, :on => :member
  get :profile_tweets, :on => :member
end
```

**_profile_tweets.html.erb**:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
<div class="question">
  <div class="header">
    <p class="body"><%= tweet.text %></p>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**profile_tweets.js.erb**:

```
$("#tabs-1").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "profile_tweets"))%>");
```

**Gemfile**:

```
gem 'twitter'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you make sure to bundle and restart your server? I've seen this error a lot after installing new gems without restarting the server.

Comment: Ah, I thought I'd restarted the server but I guess not. Now my server crashes but at least I don't get an uninitialized constant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Logan noted above, I needed to restart my server.