# How can I restart Ruby after a gem install?

Tags: ruby

I'm running on Ubuntu.  The question is so basic it feels silly but I have done some searching and can't figure out the answer.

Edit: I am running into similar issues as the following

[Uninitialized constant using Twitter ruby gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529953/uninitialized-constant-using-twitter-ruby-gem)

Comment: Ruby itself doesn't require any sort of "restarting." Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restart Ruby after installing gems.  You can for example

```
gem install rails
```

and after that you can start running rails (which uses Ruby) right away and no need to restart Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In  Uninitialized constant using Twitter ruby gem link restart means ctr+c that is stop     the server and rails s (for rails 3) that is start the server.